# JavaScript clipboardData paste plain/text instead of text/html or other media types/mime

Tags: javascript, clipboarddata

How do I only allow plain/text to be pasted instead of text/html or other media types/mimes?

Currently I'm retrieving the text but I have to use `event.preventDefault();` and manually mess around to replace the textNode in the DOM.

Here is how I get the pasted text...

```
document.getElementById('editor').onpaste = function(event)
{
 if (event.clipboardData)
 {
  text = event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
 }
 else if (window.clipboardData)
 {//IE-frigin-11
  text = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
 }
```

Is there is a way in the clipboard API to tell the browser to paste the plain/text mime instead of the text/html mime so I don't have to resort to using `event.preventDefault();` and manually adjusting the `anchorNode` `textNode`? No frameworks.